# Boost Library and closest points

Tags: c++, boost, boost-geometry, closest-points

I can find the distance between a point `MyPoint` and a polygon `MyPolygon` with

```
double dist = boost::geometry::distance(MyPoint, MyPolygon)
```

obviously the actual closest point on `MyPolygon` has to be computed somewhere. Is there an easy way to get that closest point? I can't find anything in the Boost Documentation and I'm sure others had that problem too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [source](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/boost/geometry/multi/algorithms/distance.hpp) its iterating all points of polygon inside class `distance_single_to_multi`. Its not storing the iterator, so probably you should to the same.

You can find out how to do this in [comparable_distance](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/geometry/doc/html/geometry/reference/algorithms/distance/comparable_distance.html) example.

Comment: Thank you. From some test though it looks like `return_type dist = geometry::distance(geometry, *it);` in `distance_single_to_multi` tests more than just the endpoints of the segments of the polygonboundary and the comparable_distance example does check just the endpoints. 
But in any case that means I have to write my own solution right?

Comment: @user3049681 i think yes. Seems its not very complicated.